# unexpected token { in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, highcharts

I am trying to display charts on the web using Django and highcharts.

I have passed the JSON-fomatted object as my_data from Python file into the HTML file. In order to fit the data into highchart models, I have to do some modifications inside JavaScript (pair date object with value).

I'm totally new to JavaScript and HTML,the chart is not shown.

Below is my code in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = {{ my_data | safe }};
    function parseDate(s) {
        var b = s.split(/\D+/);
        return new Date(Date.UTC(2016, --b[1], b[2]));
    };
    var lst = [];
    var date;
    for (date in obj) {
        var day_record = [parseDate(date['time']), date['pnl']];
        lst.push(day_record);
    };
    var result = lst.sort();

        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },
            title: {
                text: 'accumulated pnl'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'pnl',
                data: result
            }]
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Accumulated pnl over time </h1>
    <hr>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my_data can be displayed on the web as something like this:

```
[{"pnl": -4214918.830000036, "time": "2016-03-23 00:00:00"}, {"pnl": -5223615.250000035, "time": "2016-03-28 00:00:00"}, {"pnl": 23250409.1, "time": "2016-01-20 00:00:00"}, {"pnl": 12716814.320000006, "time": "2016-02-25 00:00:00"}, {"pnl": -9925980.870001037, "time": "2016-04-06 00:00:00"}]
```

I have tried the code through the console, and got the following error.

```
VM683:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:145:167)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:137:25)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:118:14)
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could offer me some advice!

Comment: "there must be some syntax errors or other errors inside my code" Here's how to find out: open your console (hit F12 on Windows or Opt + Cmd + I on Mac). Edit your question to include any errors you find.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I am confused why there is expected token <

Comment: You're generating some code with `{{ my_data | safe }}`. Can you show us what that generated code is? I feel pretty confident that's where your problem is.

Comment: Yes. I dumped my_data to json and passed it to the HTML file. my_data can be displayed on the web page as an array of dictionary as shown in the second block of code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

check this and compare with your code:

```
var obj = {{my_data|safe}};
function parseDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D+/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(2016, --b[1], b[2]));
};

var lst = [];
var date;
for(date in obj){
  var day_record = [parseDate(date['time']), date['pnl']];
  lst.push(day_record);
};
var result = lst.sort();
```

You have a **$** wrong positioned symbol...

**EDIT**

Also no clue why you are using jQuery to call the last part, i think only need to do the highcharts part:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
  rangeSelector : {
    selected : 1
  },

  title : {
    text : 'accumulated pnl'
  },

  series : [
    {
      name : 'pnl',
      data : result
    }]
  });
```

That should work aswell

Comment: Thank you! But still it's not working. Is that only method with JQuery is using "$" ?